# ngnix vhost setting (with apache) not pointing to my domain

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, virtualhost

i'm trying to use nginx as proxy for my apache all vhosts. i've set up a config file at

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/mydomain
```

and i'also created sym link by using a command

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mydomain /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain
```

the config file is

```
server {
       listen   80;

        root /home/mydomain/public_html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:80;
        proxy_pass 192.168.1.104:8080;

         }

         location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

i also change the Apache to listen 8080 and set the vhost to

then i had restarted the nginx and apache, but finally when i visit http://www.mydomain.com , it displays

```
Welcome to nginx!

If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Thank you for using nginx.
```

it seems the nginx was not successfully applied the vhosts file. Any ideas?

Comment: Check config with `nginx -t`. I see, you've missed protocol in `proxy_pass`.

Comment: Is that not your virtual host configuration? What is your nginx.conf content? Check if you have 'include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;' in there.

Answer (score 0):

In the proxy pass you should specify the protocol, hence following should be

```
location ~ \.php$ {
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Host $host:80;
proxy_pass http://192.168.1.104:8080;
}
```

Once changes has been done, restart the nginx server to make the changes effect.